# スライディングメニューのテンプレートを使っているのですがleft側のForm1.htmlへ画面が飛びません。どうすれば切り替わるようになるでしょうか？

Tags: onsen-ui

```xml
<ons-page>
<ons-page style="background-color: #FFF0F5">

<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="right">
    <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="app.slidingMenu.toggleMenu()">
    <ons-icon icon="bars"></ons-icon>            
    </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>

    <div class="left">
    <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="Form1.html">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-compose" fixed-width="false"
            style="font-size: 26px; vertical-align: -4px"></ons-icon>
    </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>

    <div class="center">口コミ</div>
</ons-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ons-toolbar-button ng-click="Form1.html">
```

の`ng-click`に問題があります。
`ng-click`は、クリックされた場合の処理を書かないといけません。
下記の例では`ons-navigator`を利用し、`pushPage`メソッドで`Form1.html`のページを表示させています。
※`onclick`でも同様に動作します。

```
<ons-navigator var="myNavigator">
   <ons-page>
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="right">
            <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="app.slidingMenu.toggleMenu()">
            <ons-icon icon="bars"></ons-icon>            
            </ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>

            <div class="left">
            <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('Form1.html')">
            <!--ons-toolbar-button onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('Form1.html')"-->
            <ons-icon icon="ion-compose" fixed-width="false"
                    style="font-size: 26px; vertical-align: -4px"></ons-icon>
            </ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>

            <div class="center">口コミ</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        ：
        ：
        ：省略
        ：
        ：
    </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
```

上記の例以外にもやり方はあります。
まずは、サンプルを試したり、ドキュメントを一読することをおすすめします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。他にもやり方があるんのですね。教科書の方をもう一度じっくりとよんでみます。ありがとうございました。